# Configure wso2 Identity Server Analytics to monitor wso2 Identity Server

Tags: monitor, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 IS 5.5.0 and wso2 IS Analytics 5.5.0. I wants to monitor failed logging attempts on wso2 IS and get the stats through wso2 IS Analytics. If the two servers are up and running separately how could it configure to connect wso2 IS with wso2 IS Analytics.

Imagine wso2 IS running on port:9443 and wso2 IS Analytics running on port:9444. If I make a failed login attempt via IS, how to monitor that through IS Analytics. Where should it configured to have the connection between them.

In here https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Monitoring+WSO2+IS+Using+WSO2+Analytics
it explain how a Single Sign On (SSO) can be analyzed via WSO2 IS Analytics. That's not my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this document https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Prerequisites+to+Publish+Statistics to get the understand of the prerequisites needed. Using this doc you can enable analytics for Identity server.